# Searching for general number in a word editor

Tags: search, notepad++

In a Notepad++ or an editor with similar features, is there an easy to search for a word which contains a number? For instance, suppose numbers were denoted by "~", then if I searched for "abc~" in the following text:

```
abc4
abc not a number
```

I would simply get the first word.

Comment: What do you mean by "search for a string which contains a number"?  Do you mean a quoted string? If you mean ANY string, then if there are any numbers in the document, the whole document would be a string that contains a number.  Do you mean any word that contains a number?

Comment: You're entirely correct. I meant search for a word. I just made the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "regular expression" search mode. If you just want to find groups of numbers, use `\d+`. If you want it to select the whole word containing one or more digits, use `\w*\d+\w*`.

Answer (score 2):

Type this regular expression in the Find dialog box (select the regex option):

> \w*\d\w*